# Is it possible to export a specific vuejs component to a static HTML JS code that could be rendered in browser?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I am currently working on a VueJs app for creating forms by drag and drop using "vuedraggable".

The form metadata is currently stored as a JSON object once the form is created. This form will be embedded on static websites that do not use VueJs.

What I want to achieve is that I should be able to export the code(with logic for form handling in VueJs) directly as it is previewed on the form builder page. I want to avoid additional handling of the forms on all the websites with plain javascript or jquery.

Comment: use iframe for this case

Comment: @Amaarrockz I don't want to link my form builder elsewhere. I just need to know if there's a way to export the functional  HTML & JS code directly.

Comment: Several Vue.js-based frameworks such as Nuxt.js and Gridsome are able to compile your code/app as a static site.

  [1]: https://nuxtjs.org/
  [2]: https://gridsome.org/